# Running R Shiny through RInno Package

Tags: r, shiny

I have this Shiny application that I want to run using the RInno package.

Right now my current problem is that after creating the app and then running compile_iss, I get to the setup of the application. Finally, when the application is launching it gives me the following error:

```
ERROR: Can't call `runApp()` from within `runApp()`. If your application code contains `runApp()`, please remove it.
```

My application does not contain `runApp()` anywhere inside of it.

I have included this code at the end:

```
 session$onSessionEnded(function() {
    stopApp()
    q("no")
  })
```

I end my shiny app with:

```
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Does anyone know how I can resolve that error?

Added Code:

```
ui <- fluidPage( 
  titlePanel(""),
                      h5(""),
                      sidebarLayout(
                        sidebarPanel(
                          selectInput("type", "Select Type of Record:",
                                      choices=c('A', 'B', 'C'),
                                      selected="A"),
                          DT::dataTableOutput("responses", width = 300), tags$hr(),
                          textInput("Comment", "Comments:", ""),
                          actionButton("submit", "Submit")),
                        mainPanel(    
                          plotlyOutput("plot")
                        )
                      )
             )


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  mydata <- reactive({
    invalidateLater(30 * 60000,session)
    odbcChannel<- odbcConnect("a", uid, pwd) 
    message <- sqlQuery(odbcChannel, "select a, b,c 
                        from table
                        ")
  #I got rid of all the other stuff, as I figured it was unimportant. Let me know if you need to see more

  })

session$onSessionEnded(function() {
    stopApp()
    q("no")
  })

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RInno is designed to call `runApp()` during the app's startup sequence before any of the app's code is run. `shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)` is trying to start the app a second time.

A good pre-`compile_iss` check is to run `runApp("path to ui.R/server.R")` because that is exactly how RInno tries to start the app

If you delete `shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)` from your app, it should fix the error, but let me know if you are still having an issue and I would be happy to troubleshoot it with you!

Comment: I have taken out shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server). The error still appears unfortunately.

Comment: make sure your files have the right names. ui.R and server.R everything else should be sourced in one of these two. @DavieD

Comment: Can you share more of your app's code? Is it using app.R or a combination of ui.R, server.R and global.R?

Comment: Is that file called app.R?

Comment: It was not, I renamed it app. Now I get a different error : ERROR: app.R did not return a shiny.appobj object. Does this have to deal with my shiny code?

Comment: Yep, you should break them out into ui.R and server.R files similar to the example_app

Comment: I have got it to work now, thank you for all the help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151992/discussion-between-davie-d-and-jonathan-hill).

Comment: @JonathanHill can you please look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72834154/r-shiny-make-path-location-in-dt-table-column-clickable-and-navigable?noredirect=1#comment128646713_72834154)? It would also be helpful if you could create a tag of your package, thank you.